# How do I get event log information from pyethereum?

Tags: python, ethereum

I've got some tests that create contracts with pyethereum and do various things with them, but I'm puzzled over how to get information about events they log.

A simplified example:

```
from ethereum import tester as t

s = t.state()
code = """contract LogTest {
            event LogMyNumber(uint);

            function LogTest() {
            }

            function logSomething() {
                LogMyNumber(4); 
            }
        }"""

logtest = t.state().abi_contract(code, language='solidity', sender=t.k0)
logtest.logSomething()

#number_i_logged = WHAT DO I DO HERE?
#print "You logged the number %d" % (number_i_logged)
```

I run this and get:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "eth.pow"
{'': 4, '_event_type': 'LogMyNumber'}
```

That json that's getting printed is the information I want, but can someone explain, or point me to an example, of how I might capture it and load it into a variable in python so that I can check it and do something with it? There seems to be something called log_listener that you can pass into abi_contract that looks like it's related but I couldn't figure out what to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you've been waiting for an answer for quite a long time, but in case someone else is wondering, here is goes:
log_listeners you mentioned is the way to go. You can find some sample code using it in [pyethereum's tests](https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/8f5eea75cd8e44b7d9cc1d98009a2ed856287030/ethereum/tests/test_contracts.py#L1513), and here is your fixed code:

```
from ethereum import tester as t

s = t.state()
code = """contract LogTest {
            event LogMyNumber(uint loggedNumber);

            function LogTest() {
            }

            function logSomething() {
                LogMyNumber(4);
            }
        }"""

c = s.abi_contract(code, language='solidity', sender=t.k0)
o = []
s.block.log_listeners.append(lambda x: o.append(c._translator.listen(x)))

c.logSomething()

assert len(o) == 1
assert o == [{"_event_type": 'LogMyNumber', "loggedNumber": 4}]

number_i_logged = o[0]["loggedNumber"]
print "You logged the number %d" % (number_i_logged)
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Working great, and just in time for me to need to do this again. Thanks again.

Comment: Great, glad it helped.